# android: how to add attribute to the body ‘s child Element in xmpp

Tags: xmpp, smack

i want to send a message in XMPP just like this:

```
<message from='86@this' to='861@this' type='chat'>
<body>
 <number id=279
      title='hi'
      word='hello boy'/>
</body>
</message>
```

Comment: Why would you put the number inside the <body>? The body is for humand-readable text. See http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/XMPP_IM_Client_Design_Guidelines#When_making_a_custom_extension.2C_add_new_elements_to_.3Cmessage.3E.2C_.3Ciq.3E_or_.3Cpresence.3E_stanzas

Comment: RFC 6120/6121 disallow elements within `<body/>`. Put your data into a custom extension element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify the `Message` class `toXML()` method

```
if(defaultBody != null){
      buf.append("<body>);
        if(number != null){
           buf.append("<number").append("id=\"").append(id).append("\"").append("/>");
        }
  }
```

add like this, I hope it will help you.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

RFC 6120/6121 disallow elements within `<body/>`. Put your data into a custom extension element.